# RoutingError with ActionController (GET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to set 7 directories, in 7 subdomains, using Rails + nginx + unicorn + MongoDB.

Actually, the subdomains are generated from root files by nginx and works perfectly, and I didn't use MongoDB yet.
Installations are **freshly made**, no pages created yet (and I also have tried with), and I still have 404 errors with an error in log. 
Works if I create a html page in `/public`, of course.

**Example:**

I install one of them using `rails new site1`

in `/var/www/site1`

available on `http://site1.mydomain.tld`

It will display this error in `/var/www/site1/log/production.log` :

```
 I, [2013-09-01T02:12:44.425694 #31368]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX at 2013-09-01 02:12:44 +0200
F, [2013-09-01T02:12:44.426541 #31368] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
  unicorn (4.6.3) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

There's my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bson_ext'

# mongoDB tool
## gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.0.0'
## gem 'mongo', '~> 1.9.2'
#gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use unicorn as the app server
  gem 'unicorn'

# CSS tool
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

## JQUERY & javascript stuff
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

My `config/unicorn.rb` file :

```
root = "/var/www/site1"
 working_directory root
 pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
 stderr_path "#{root}/log/uni-err.log"
 stdout_path "#{root}/log/uni-out.log"

 listen "/tmp/site1-unicorn.test.sock"
 worker_processes 2
 timeout 30
```

Any help would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have made a change to your route and did not restart. In order to view these changes, you must restart the service.

Comment: Unfortunately I've just tried. And it does not changed anything. Atleast, now I know that all services starts correctly at boot !
But I still get 404's page from Rails public folder...

Comment: what is your routes file ?

Comment: `Site1::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'index', to: 'hello#index'
end`

... But I just saw that the demo works with `Rails server`, on port 3000. So that's probably a problem related to Unicorn (or nginx ?)

Comment: have you check [this](http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/) and [this](http://dave.is/unicorn.html) ?